# Trying to show popup modal from js in a if statement, provided the number entered in the form is correct

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog, popup

I am trying to show the activate a pop up modal, using the js script, but I have an error in my code, I am not sure where I should call for the modal to show within the if statement. Please help. my js code below. So if The number in the form is 10 digits then it should be able to send details to my php script and then show a success/thankyou modal.

I was earlier using HTML to toggle the modal using data-bs-toggle and target in the attributes for the button, but i was told to activate the modal from the js if it needs to corelate with the validation of the number. so here is everything...

```
    var number = $("#mobile").val();

if (number.length == 10 && number != null ) {
    var input = {
        "mobile" : number,
        "email": email,
        "name": name,
        "residence_type":residence_type,
        "action" : "just_email"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'controller.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : input,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
        
    })
    
    $("#formsubmit1").click (function(){
        $("#thankyouPopup2").modal("Toggle");}
        
} else {
    $(".error").html('Please enter a valid number!')
    $(".error").show();
}
```

}

Here is the HTML script for the same form.

```
 <section class="banner_section section_padding position-relative pb-0">
    <div class="hanging_form bg-white">
        <h2 class="colorTheme text-center fw-bold mb-4">Let's Connect</h2>
        <div class="custom_form_style">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control name"  id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Number" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3 send_me_updates position-relative">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sendMeUpdates">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="sendMeUpdates">
                            Send me project updates
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3 flat_size">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="2bhk" name ="residence_type[]" value="2bhk">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="2bhk">2BHK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="3bhk" name ="residence_type[]" value="3bhk">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="3bhk">3BHK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="4bhk" name ="residence_type[]" value="4bhk">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="4bhk">4BHK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="villa" name ="residence_type[]" value="villa">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="villa">Villa</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-outer d-table mx-auto mt-5 position-relative">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id ="formsubmit1"  onclick="sendOTP()" >Submit</button>

                    <div class="error"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay!!! So I got this working, Feels nice to ask my first question and answer it my self a few hours later, Also my first answer on Stack overflow. So I kept googling and trying , and trying, [a few moments later..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZV9.jpg) Voila.. it was a simple fix, shown in the code below. hope this thread helps someone.

```
var number = $("#mobile").val();

if (number.length == 10 && number != null ) {
    var input = {
        "mobile" : number,
        "email": email,
        "name": name,
        "residence_type":residence_type,
        "action" : "just_email"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'controller.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : input,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
        
    })
    
    $("#thankyouPopup2").modal("show");

        
} else {
    $(".error").html('Please enter a valid 10 digit number!')
    $(".error").show();
}
```

}